# Help with rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

Ok guys, so I'm making a scheduler.

So I have two tables so far, 
Shows with "title:string" and "description:text" and I also have
ShowTime; with "show_id:integer", "day:string", and "show_time:time".

I did the has_many, and belongs_to, I honestly do not know where to go from here on,

I want a user to be able to add the times when creating a new show. What would I do? I was looking at some rails associations documentations, seems like I would be making something like,

```
@showtime = @shows.showtimes.create(:show_id => show.id, :day => DAY, :show_time => TIME)
```

Notice I put just DAY and TIME, because I also honestly don't know how I'll fetch this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your interface. But for simplicity, let's assume you provided two select boxes for selecting day and time, and have to add `ShowTime` one by one.

And assume you have rest resources:

```
map.resources :shows do |show|
  show.resources :show_times
end
```

The form: (given a @show object created already)

```
<% form_for @show_time, :url => show_show_time_path(@show) do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :day %>: <%= form.select :day, [["Mon", "mon"], ["Tue", "tue"]], {} %>
  <%= form.label :show_time %>: <%= form.select :show_time, [["Slot 1", "09:00"]], {} %>
<% end %>
```

You should provide your best way to generate the `day` & `show_time` arrays. They are in the following structure:

`[["Text", "value"], ["Text", "value"]]`

which will generate something like:

`<option value="value">Text</option>`

After the form is submitted, in your create action:

```
def create
  @show = Show.find params[:show_id] # this params[:show_id] is from the rest resource's path
  @show_time = @show.show_times.build(params[:show_time]) # this params[:show_time] is from the form you submitted

  if @show_time.save
    flash[:notice] = "Success"
    redirect_to show_show_time_path(@show, @show_time)
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Failed"
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for you help. I guess I need to go read some more tutorials, because I don't understand half of the things you said. I don't have rest recources, So far, I only did the show & showtime scaffolds, migration, then added the "has_many" and "belongs_to".

Comment: If you open your `routes.rb`, you should see two resources `map.resources :shows` and `map.resources :showtimes`. Scaffolds uses restful resources also. But I'm afraid it didn't generate nested resources for you. Is it the case?